# How to find out why rails app uses a lot of memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, heroku

I am using Heroku and today I started seeing a lot of `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` errors. What is the best way (or tool) to track this down and find what uses up all memory?

Answer (score 2):

Install New Relic. Here you go: https://newrelic.com/.

Also, you probably want to check that you are not loading a lot of stuff via Active Record. For example, doing a `Comment.all` is probably not a very good idea if you have, say, 10000 comments. Instead, do something like `Comment.find_in_batches` which is slightly more memory friendly.

Comment: I have new relic now... Is there a way to understand what uses all that memory?